# /Android/ Play Video using a saved string path

Tags: java, android, video

I am new to Android Programming. I'm currently doing a video player like app but having a problem. The app goes this way:

- I choose a video
- Video path will save using putString (function)? as you can see the code below
- When 'play' button gets clicked, the video will play
- Now when i relaunch the app, the video path is still saved but if i click the 'play' button, android would show an error, 'cant play this video' so i need to repick a video again.

What I want in my app is even if you close the app, I wouldn't be needing to choose a video to play when i relaunch it. I want it to play the video of the path saved. I hope it's possible.

Here is the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  AlarmManager alarmManager;
  private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
  private static final int MY_INTENT_CLICK=302;
  private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
  private static MainActivity inst;
  String meduri;


 public static MainActivity instance() {
      return inst;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    meduri = prefs.getString("key", "");

    Button chs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose);
    chs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chooseMed();
        }
    });
}

public void chooseMed(){
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("video/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(data != null) {
        setVid(data.getDataString());
    }
}

public void setVid(String uriq){
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("key", uriq);
    editor.apply();
    meduri = uriq;
}

public void playvid(){
    VideoView vdeo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    vdeo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    vdeo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(meduri));
    vdeo.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    vdeo.requestFocus();
    vdeo.start();
}
```

}

I hope you could help me with my problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement for the `Uri` you get back from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to be usable for a long period of time. You will have temporary access to its contents, but perhaps not permanent access.

This is very similar to Web development. A URL may be something that you can save and use later, but if the server requires a session cookie or some other form of user authentication/authorization, the URL may not be usable in the future.

If you use the Storage Access Framework, available on Android 4.4+, you can request persistent `Uri` permissions, which, if granted, will give you longer-term access to the content. Those `Uri` values can be saved and used later.